# Minimize the sum total of Type I and Type II errors

Tags: statistics

X is a random variable with density $f(x)=\theta e^{-\theta x}, x>0$. (So X is an Exponential($\frac{1}{\theta}$) distribution.) Consider $H_0: \theta=1$ versus $H_1: \theta=\frac{1}{2}$.

I need to find the test minimizing the sum total of Type I and Type II errors.

I used the Neymann-Pearson theorem to find the best critical region: $\displaystyle \sum ^n_{i=1}X_i \ge c$.

As the X's are exponential functions, $Y=\displaystyle \sum ^n_{i=1}X_i$~Gamma$(n, \frac{1}{\theta})$.

Then, I believe that I need to minimize $P(Y\ge c|\theta=1)+P(Y<c|\theta=\frac{1}{2})$, as this would be the sum of Type I and Type II errors.

However, this is where I get stuck, as I believe that the CDF of the Gamma distribution can actually be calculated by hand.

Where should I go from here? Am I missing a crucial step? I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

The CDF involves an incomplete gamma function, which cannot be easily calculated when $n$ is not an integer. However, it is possible to do it for an integer because you could just use integration by parts the integral below

$\int x^{n-1} e^{(1/\theta) x} \text{dx}$

Integrate the exponential part and differentiate $x^{n-1}$ part, but this is not going to be particular nice.

If you want a quick answer, $\Gamma (n,\lambda)$ for integer $n$ is also known as Erlang distribution. The explicit CDF is given in the wiki link:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_distribution